# Getting "Invalid command 'SSLOpenSSLConfCmd'" when using Apache 2.4.10 and Debian 7?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, ssl

I've upgraded my Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4.10 on Debian 7 (Wheezy) in order to use stronger DH keys. I've also upgraded openssl to OpenSSL 1.0.1k.

I've been trying to add the following command to my Apache2 configuration:

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd DHParameters "/etc/ssl/private/dhparams_4096.pem"
```

But every time I add this in to the config file I receive the following error:

> AH00526: Syntax error on line 83 of
>   /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf:
>   Invalid command
>   'SSLOpenSSLConfCmd', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not
>   included in the server configuration Action 'configtest' failed.

From what I've seen on the internet this error occurs when using a version of Apache before 2.4.8. I'm using 2.4.10, so I can rule this out as an issue. Does anyone have any idea what could cause this issue?

**EDIT:**
Thinking that the issue could have been with the version of OpenSSL that I am using, I have installed OpenSSL 1.0.2 from the "Stretch" repos. It's installed correctly, I restarted Apache and it seems to work. However, I go to add the above comment in I get the same error.

**EDIT 2:**
I've studied the `phpinfo();` output and I've noticed this under the OpenSSL section:

```
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
OpenSSL Header Version      OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
```

I've gone back on to the server and ran `openssl version`, which has given this output:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
```

So for whatever reason Apache doesn't recognise the newer version of OpenSSL on the system. I've restarted Apache several times, the server has been rebooted, but the phpinfo() output remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

As I had still used the stretch repo, I issued this command:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

This basically upgrades PHP, and doing this fixed the OpenSSL issue I had where it was using the older version, and it has also now fixed the Apache 'SSLOpenSSLConfCmd' issue too.